# Как с эффектом убрать элементы li из списка ul

Tags: jquery

Возникли сложности с эффектом Jquery.
По клику нужно убрать элементы li списка ul влево или вправо, как бы плавно прокрутить, чтобы на место убранных вставились новые li
Как это сделать? Буду очень благодарен за подсказки

Answer (score 2):

Плавное перемещение и исчезновение / появление элементов [можно](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-effects/) [реализовать](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp) с помощью метода [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate1)

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите совсем красиво, то советую посмотреть в сторону [effeckt.css](http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/dist/).